# IE click event at wrong position due to overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, internet-explorer-11

I've got a list of elements with a jQuery click listener that simply adds a class to the clicked `<li>` element.
This unordered list is nested in a few `<div>` elements which are placed and transformed with `transform: matrix3d(...)` attributes. The lists overflow should be hidden.
This works perfectly fine in Chrome, but IE11 (11.0.x) has some problems. Clicking a `<li>` element causes a fired event at a totally different `<li>` element.
For some reasons I have to make use of this matrix transforms and I also need these overflows. But perhaps you are aware of a neat workaround or just can state that this is a common bug in IE and not solvable.

This is the MWE:

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected-li')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected-li');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selected-li');
  }
});
```

```css
.myContainer {
  position: absolute;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clientList {
  height: 333px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.selected-li {
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: #008CD6;
}

body {
  background-color: #888888;
}

#d-01 {
  background-color: #565656;
}

#d-01 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#d-02 {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#d-03 {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

#d-04 {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="d-01" class="myContainer" style="width: 1878.12px; height: 993.96px; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 54, 99, 1, 1);">
    <div id="d-02" class="myContainer overflow-hidden" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1);">
      <div id="d-03" class="myContainer" style="width: 55%; height: 70%; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 422.577, 149.094, 1, 1);">
        <ul id="d-04" class="clientList">
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
          <li>TEST_X</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you so far.

Comment: Hey, so if the list's overflow should be hidden you need to remove   overflow-y: auto; from the class .clientList. As for your event error I can't reproduce.